# Pure Data freezing and not outputting audio

Tags: windows, audio, freeze, asio, puredata

I have downloaded and re-installed Pure Data. When running media -> Test audio and MIDI, there are three test tone settings: 80, 60, off. Nothing comes out when I use either of these. Everything is on and engaged but there's no sound. At the moment I try to run ASIO, I lose the ability to close out of Pd altogether. Additionally, I can't play audio in or outside of Pd. If I want to hear anything ever again, I have to restart the computer, despite the speakers being unmuted.

Comment: You checked the 'compute audio' box, yes?

Comment: of course. that was the first thing i did

Comment: You could try installing an asio driver, then

Comment: i did. puredata suggested it so i downloaded and installed it. Still, it hasn't fixed this problem

Comment: i have an asio folder with 2 .dll files in it. when i try selecting the asio driver through Pd, the asio config window pops up and then I can't close ANYTHING related to Pd unless, again, i restart the computer. can't even force quit

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a system that might have characters other than ASCII?  Things like accented letters, umlauts, enye, or even different alphabets like cyrillic, korean, greek, chinese, japanese?  That has been a common cause of issues like this, and has recently been fixed.  Try downloading the latest version:

http://puredata.info/downloads/pd-extended/releases/0.43.4